# Insert a blank paragraph in a document with tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using `InsertParagraphBefore` or `InsertParagraphAfter` a paragraph can be inserted in a Word document at any point. However, once there are tables in the document the instruction will be carried out differently if the insertion point is before or after a table and differently again if it is at the end of the document. I spent a long Sunday afternoon researching this topic and created a function that inserts a paragraph where it is expected. I invite suggestions to improve it or perhaps render it irrelevant even, as I believe it, in fact, should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function InsertBlankPara(Rng As Range, _
                         Optional ByVal Before As Boolean) As Range
    ' SSY 001 01 Nov 2020

    ' ======================================================
    ' Rng           may be a single paragraph or part thereof
    '                   or a table or part thereof
    ' Before        Insert the paragraph before Rng if True
    '                   [False by default, appending the paragraph]
    ' ======================================================
    ' Return value  the inserted paragraph
    ' Return object Rng will expand the original Rng to include the
    '               entire table or paragraph it comprised originally
    '               plus the paragraph that was added
    ' ======================================================

    Dim Pstart      As Long
    Dim Pend        As Long
    Dim IsTbl       As Boolean

    With Rng
        IsTbl = .Information(wdWithInTable)
        .Expand IIf(IsTbl, wdTable, wdParagraph)
        Pstart = .Start
        Pend = .End + 1
        .Collapse IIf(Before, wdCollapseStart, wdCollapseEnd)
        If IsTbl Then .Move wdCharacter, IIf(Before, -1, _
                                         IIf(.Document.Range.End <= Pend, 2, 0))
        
        If IsTbl Or Before Then
            .InsertParagraphBefore
        Else
            .Move wdCharacter, IIf(.Document.Range.End < Pend, 0, -1)
            .InsertParagraphAfter
        End If
        
        Set Rng = .Document.Range(Pstart, Pend)
        If Before Then
            Pend = Pstart + 1
        Else
            Pstart = Pend - 1
        End If
        Set InsertBlankPara = .Document.Range(Pstart, Pend)
    End With
End Function
```